# oracle to postgresql Migration

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

Till now I am working in a project with Oracle database with lot of query,procedure,functions,sequences.But Oracle license term is going to finished.

So as per requirement project need to migrate from oracle to PostgreSQL.So my question is what are those important factors(functions/predefined tables etc...) are going to give me problem or I need to put special attention.

And how to check for performance issues ?

Comment: http://ora2pg.darold.net/ can help you a lot but you will have to migrate the PL/SQL code manually.

Comment: how to check for performance issues.